# Updating MainActivity variable after OKHttp

Tags: android, list, okhttp

I am using OKHttp to pull data from a server and looking to update a List object variable in MainActivity after a buttonclick. The code requires two button clicks during the initial launching of the application( instead of one click) to update the list. How do I get the updated List, after  one click( the way it should work). Note that I tried different scenarios, such as making the List object static and updating in the thread and after the thread has been completed. My condense code is below.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();
    Button button;
    public TextView jsonTextView;
    String url =   "http://www.mocky.io/v2/5aa0d0c8320000941ce9fd7c";
    private static List<ClientsInfo> infoData; //static variable to be 
                                           //updated after threading 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       button = findViewById(R.id.button);
       infoData = new ArrayList();
       button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getJsonDataAndProcess();
            }
        });
    }

    private void getJsonDataAndProcess() {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) 
                        throws IOException {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    final String myResponse = response.body().string();
                    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                             formatJsonData(myResponse);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void formatJsonData(String response){
        try{
            //Json object of the parsed data
            JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(response);
            if( infoData != null)
                infoData.clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < JA.length(); i++){

                JSONObject JO = (JSONObject) JA.get(i);
                ClientsInfo info = new ClientsInfo();//object stored in list
                info.setId_Number( Integer.toString((Integer) JO.get("id")));
                info.setFirst_Name((String) JO.get("first_name"));
                info.setLast_Name((String) JO.get("last_name"));
                info.setEmail((String) JO.get("email"));
                info.setGender((String) JO.get("gender"));
                info.setIp_Address((String) JO.get("ip_address"));
                infoData.add(info);
            }
        } catch(Exception e){
            Log.i("ERROR2", e.toString());
        }
    }
}
//end of mainActivity
```

Comment: Where is your `ListView` and the adapter you are using to populate your `ListView`?

Comment: To simplified the question, I removed the listView and arrayadapter code. The listview and adapter code works. However, I still must click the button twice to get the accurate list content when launching the app and performing the click action. Note the size of my list should be 4. When I buttonclick initially, the list size is 0( and no list view, which makes sense). When I buttonclick the second time, i get the correct list size and my listview is displayed accurately

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add `notifyDataSetChanged` in your `formatJsonData` function once you have populated the list of info.

```
public void formatJsonData(String response){
    try{
        //Json object of the parsed data
        JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(response);
        if(infoData != null)
            infoData.clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < JA.length(); i++){
            JSONObject JO = (JSONObject) JA.get(i);
            ClientsInfo info = new ClientsInfo();//object stored in list
            info.setId_Number( Integer.toString((Integer) JO.get("id")));
            info.setFirst_Name((String) JO.get("first_name"));
            info.setLast_Name((String) JO.get("last_name"));
            info.setEmail((String) JO.get("email"));
            info.setGender((String) JO.get("gender"));
            info.setIp_Address((String) JO.get("ip_address"));
            infoData.add(info);
        }

        // Just call the notifyDataSetChanged here on your adapter.
        yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    } catch(Exception e){
        Log.i("ERROR2", e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Great to know that it helped. You are welcome. Please upvote and accept the answer if you found the answer helpful.